# Substitute second digit of a column with a constant number linux

Tags: linux, substitution, editing

I have a table like:

```
Person age
name1 45
name2 13
name3 28
name4 89
```

I would like, in an automatised way (since it's a big table) , to modify the second digit of the second table for a 0, so that I have decade groups instead of exact age number:

```
Person age
name1 40
name2 10
name3 20
name4 80
```

Which is the neatest way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, it does the trick ( just remove the first line from your input file )

```
#!/bin/bash

file_path="/home/mobaxterm/Desktop/f.txt"
dest_file="/home/mobaxterm/Desktop/f2.txt"

echo "Person age" > /home/mobaxterm/Desktop/f2.txt
while read p; do

  name=$(echo "$p" | cut -f1 -d' ')
  age=$(echo "$p" | cut -f2 -d' ' | sed 's/\(.\{1\}\)./\10/')
  echo "$name $age" >> /home/mobaxterm/Desktop/f2.txt

done < $file_path
```